# How can i call specific data from database to add in my with message in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I include the name of the particular data to my return information-message?

**UserController:**

```
 public function process(Request $request){
    $validated = $request->validate([   
       "email" => ['required', 'email'],
       'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(auth()->attempt($validated)){
       $request->session()->regenerate();

       return redirect('/')->with('information-message', 'Welcome Back!');
    }

    return redirect('login')->with('failed-message', 'Login Failed. Please Try Again!');

 }
```

**information-message.blade.php:**

```
 @if (session()->has('information-message'))

<div x-data="{show : true}" x-show="show" x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 5000)" class="flex fixed m-2 bottom-0 right-0 z-20 items-center bg-blue-700 text-white text-sm font-bold px-4 py-3" role="alert">
    <svg class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M12.432 0c1.34 0 2.01.912 2.01 1.957 0 1.305-1.164 2.512-2.679 2.512-1.269 0-2.009-.75-1.974-1.99C9.789 1.436 10.67 0 12.432 0zM8.309 20c-1.058 0-1.833-.652-1.093-3.524l1.214-5.092c.211-.814.246-1.141 0-1.141-.317 0-1.689.562-2.502 1.117l-.528-.88c2.572-2.186 5.531-3.467 6.801-3.467 1.057 0 1.233 1.273.705 3.23l-1.391 5.352c-.246.945-.141 1.271.106 1.271.317 0 1.357-.392 2.379-1.207l.6.814C12.098 19.02 9.365 20 8.309 20z"/></svg>
    <p>{{session('information-message')}}</p>
  </div>

@endif
```

If successful login:
Instead of Welcome Back, I want the output to become Welcome Back! (name of the user who login).

Comment: Please consider telling more details about your code, your problem and your question. What name? What data? What does your code do that you want it to do? What does it do that you don't want it to do? ...

Comment: When I log in, my program displays "Welcome Back! But I want to get the message 'Welcome Back! <name of user who login>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Auth faccade to get the current user.

```
 Auth::user()
```

In your case

```
return redirect('/')->with('information-message', 'Welcome Back! '.Auth::user()->name);
```

Comment: For slightly more neatness, use sprintf: return redirect('/')->with('information-message', sprintf('Welcome Back! %s', Auth::user()->name));